# change language of speech / text dictation with keyboard shortcut

Tags: keyboard, language, voice-dictation

I have my dictation feature set up with two languages. Both of them work, but to change the language I always need to click on the small pop up dialogue twice with my mouse.

For accessibility reasons, I would like to switch the language with my keyboard, as I am often communicating in two languages.

Is there an option for this? I tried changing the input source for the whole keyboard, while switching between English and German works for the keyboard input, this does not at all impact the language for the dictation.

[image: dictation settings in mac OS]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I change the language for dictation on the fly?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/59323/how-can-i-change-the-language-for-dictation-on-the-fly)

Comment: @Thinkr unfortunately not. I can verify the property being written as well as the process being killed, it does however not seem to impact the language the next time I start dictation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is new since Sonoma / macOS 14, but:

I have now configured two languages for my input source (even though I don't want or need English keyboard input). Changing that language with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> also switches the input for the voice dictation.

Comment: Yes, new in Sonoma, and rather annoying for users who do not want their keyboard to change with their dictation language.